# Install Ubuntu Server via SSH

Tags: server, ssh

I registered for a domain and a online hosting on GoDaddy.com. I only have access to it via their website and SSH. Is there any way to install Ubuntu server on this so that I log into Ubuntu via SSH instead of the current OS?

Comment: Hosting you meant is a shared host? If so, its neither manageable nor have access to the root. If its a VPS, the host will give you option to choose the OS. Upon selection the host them-self will install on your behalf along with their pre-compiled script and security updates, configurations... etc. There are various types of services.. I'm not sure which one you've subscribed to but I don't think any of the provider gives you the option to install the OS you have but the available list from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you decided what operating system to use when you signed up with them.
If you picked Windows, Fedora or CentOS you wont be using Ubuntu. If you chose Ubuntu it will be the version they installed for you. This only applies to dedicated servers.

If you have a managed Virtual Private Server Ubuntu is not even an option.

Comment: I chose linux when I signed up. Is there any way I can use commands like sudo or apt-get?